# Systemd TightVNC Multi User

Tags: systemd, tightvnc

This may have already been answered before, but if it has, my google foo isn't strong enough to find it.
I'm running a TightVNC server and I want multiple users to connect to it. I have found the ability to do this with legacy runlevels with init.d, but not with systemd.

I have been attempting to create a system service with arguments to start the service for different users - as opposed to having a user specific script that they are responsible for executing as I want to control the ports and execution.

I have come up with the below, however, the if statement doesn't work. Is there a way that I can have a single service like this? Or do I need to duplicate them for each user?

Thanks.

```
[Unit]
Description=Start TightVNC server at startup
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
if [ 1 == %i]; then
 User = user1
 Group = user1
 WorkingDirectory=/home/user1
 PIDFile = /home/user1/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
elif [2 == %i]; then
 User = user2
 Group = user2
 WorkingDirectory=/home/user2
 PIDFile = /home/user2/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
fi

ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1280x800 -localhost :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013329/systemd-unit-file-template-for-multiple-users

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly